# WPS Push-Button for Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, iot, wps

Is there any such thing like the WPS Push-Button function for Bluetooth?

I would like to connect a headless IoT device to a smartphone. Unfortunately the IoT device has no input capability (just a button).

Comment: Have the phone scan, then connect to the IoT device. If it asks for a pin, try 0000.

Comment: Are you asking so that you can develop a headless IOT device, or do you have an actual device that you've purchased that you're trying to connect?  Typically headless bluetooth devices with only one button require you to press and hold that one button to make them discoverable.  Then the phone can search for them and the phone initiates paring. As bib suggests a common trope, if pin codes are required is to just use 0000 but this varies from device to device.